# How can I draft a reminder email when I'm not sure if the agreement is still valid and still have it formal?

Tags: email

A couple of months ago, a professor asked me to help him do some research i.e. take a research assistance position online. I was supposed to begin last week, but he has not reached out yet, and at this point I'm not sure if he forgot or changed his mind about this.  I am finding it difficult to email him with a reminder.  My draft of the email is below. I would appreciate any help.

> Subject: Re: Research Assistance
>
> Dear Professor X,
>
> I was hoping I could begin the research soon. Please let me know how can I be of help.
>
> Thanks and regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you jump in too fast, remind him of the circumstances first. Be more specific.

> In March we spoke about me doing some research on one of your projects, and I expressed interest in doing that. If this position is still available, I am still interested and would very much like to pursue it. Please let me know either way.
> Thanks and regards,
> [contact information]